# What's the difference between pagecontainer change and mobile navigate?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

jQuery Mobile 1.4 has (at least) two methods to change pages:

1. `$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer('change', '/test')` [[Pagecontainer API](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#method-change)]
2. `$.mobile.navigate('/test')` [[AJAX Navigation](http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/demos/navigation/)]

There's also a Pagecontainer "load" method but that appears to be a lower-level hook.

When would I use one instead of the other, or are they interchangeable?

Comment: `navigate` is responsive to browser's buttons back/forward. `change` and `navigate` changes pages but the first updates url history and does transition animation, the latter doesn't update url history.

Comment: @Omar I just tested on JQM 1.4 and 1) navigate also updates URL history, 2) navigate also does a transition animation, and 3) pagecontainer change is also responsive to the browser's back button. Have I misunderstood any points?

Comment: good to know, i will try to find out more.

Comment: I removed my answer since I got it wrong as it seems. I'll have to check it out and come back with a better answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.navigate/ `$.mobile.navigate` is a low-level feature and should not be used.

extract about "navigate":

> Note: This method is a low-level utility which can be used on its own. If you use the jQuery Mobile navigation framework, you should not separately use this utility. Instead, **you should use pagecontainer methods** to navigate to another page.

However, if you want to "navigate" before page initialization is complete, you will need to call `$.mobile.navigate`.
Otherwise, with `pagecontainer("change", ...)`, you will get this error:

> Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on pagecontainer prior to initialization;

Comment: Not really, you can change directly like so: `$('body').pagecontainer( "change", "#target" );`